# Difference between SpatialJoin with "...where..." and "join...on..."

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-database

I wonder where the difference between these two spatial joins is and, if there is a difference, when to use which.

```
SELECT *
FROM points p, shapes s
WHERE ST_Within(p.geom, s.geom);
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM points p
INNER JOIN shapes s ON ST_Within(p.geom, s.geom)
```

Is one faster in certain situations?

Comment: The difference is stylistic, but when your tasks expand to joining twelve to fifteen tables, you'll see why experienced SQL coders use `JOIN` exclusively.  Unfortunately, as written, this is more of a pure SQL question, and *opinion* bait at that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one difference for both statement. Postgresql converts both it to the same query plan. You can see plans by just add `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` before your select and looks for result.

Comment: is one considered faster than the other?

Comment: must be no. Postgresql converts both it to the same query plan. You can see plans by just add `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` before your select and looks for result.

Comment: I prefer the JOIN because it's too easy to forget the condition when mixed in WHERE.  Also with the JOIN approach, you can use a LEFT to for example find points that are not within any shape.  You can't do that with the WHERE