# Difference between JOIN ON and WHERE in Virtual Layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql, virtual-layer

There is already a question on this topic [Difference between SpatialJoin with “…where…” and “join…on…”](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227089/difference-between-spatialjoin-with-where-and-join-on). However, it is dedicated to PostGIS.

Since in the Virtual Layer query window, I cannot simply proceed with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` command before my `SELECT`, therefore cannot see the difference between two queries and moreover it uses SQLite and SpatiaLite to operate.

So, what is the difference between those queries in terms of Virtual Layers and QGIS?

```sql
SELECT d.id, COUNT(p.id) PoInPol
FROM districts AS d, points AS p
WHERE st_within(p.geometry, d.geometry)
GROUP BY d.id
```

Versus

```sql
SELECT d.id, COUNT(p.id) PoInPol
FROM districts AS d
JOIN points AS p ON st_within(p.geometry, d.geometry)
GROUP BY d.id
```

Those queries simply give a number of points inside each feature of districts layer.

Comment: I test the different codes on sqlite (I assume QGIS use Spatialite for Virtual Layers) with an `EXPLAIN` and the query plan is the same.

Comment: I don't want to because I test it on sqlite, not spatialite with the `ST_WITHIN` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DB Query Planners are (usually) smart and will rewrite the query to make it the most efficient. BUT, there is still a difference between the two queries (especially if we ignore the planner intervention).

For the example in the question, it makes no difference. If you use `LEFT`/`RIGHT`/`OUTER JOIN`s, it does. If you add extra conditions, it also makes a difference. And if you have several joins, it can have a great impact, both in terms of results and efficiency.

When the filtering condition is put inside the `JOIN`, it is evaluated right away and only rows satisfying the condition are used in the next join.

When the filtering condition is put in the `WHERE` clause, it is evaluated at the end, so all rows are considered.

```sql
SELECT a.id
FROM a,b,c
WHERE a.id = b.id AND b.id = c.id
AND a.val=1 AND b.val=2 AND c.val=3;
```

--> do a `CROSS JOIN` between a,b,c. From all rows (so a size * b size * c size), keep the ones satisfying the condition.

```sql
SELECT a.id
FROM a
JOIN B ON a.id = b.id AND a.val = 1 AND b.val = 2
JOIN C ON b.id = c.id AND c.val = 3;
```

--> get all rows from A. Keep the rows having `a.val=1`. Match rows in B by `id` and keep only the rows having `b.val=2`. Using this partial result set, match rows in C by `id` and keep the rows having `c.val=3`

Using a `LEFT JOIN`, the difference is in the result. Suppose we have an entry in table A with no match (by ID) in table B.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.val =2;
```

--> the row that exists only in A is kept in the join. The `WHERE` clause filters it out.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON a.id = b.id AND b.val = 2;
```

--> There is no row in B matching the row ID and `b.val`, so the right side of the join is NULL. Since there is a row on the left side of the join, the row is returned (`A.*` is populated, `B.*` is null)

Comment: This answer is generic from the title, and may be off-topic for the specific query written in the question.

Comment: It's more a SQL trap to avoid and in the particular case of a `LEFT JOIN`, the correct writing is in the first case `WHERE b.val =2 or b.val IS NULL;`, so `A.*` is populated.