# Selecting lines where start and end points within polygon using Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis-2, spatial-query, virtual-layer

In QGIS 2.18 project there are several layers, lines and polygons respectively

[image: input]

My task is to select all lines when their start and end points are laying within polygons using Virtual Layer, see image below.

[image: result]

I can achieve the result that I want with the following query

```sql
WITH start_p AS (
SELECT l.id AS start_id
FROM line AS l, "Layer_2" AS p
WHERE ST_within(start_point(l.geometry),p.geometry)
),

end_p AS (
SELECT l.id AS end_id
FROM line AS l, "Layer_2" AS p
WHERE ST_within(end_point(l.geometry),p.geometry)
)

SELECT *
FROM line AS l, start_p, end_p
WHERE l.id = start_p.start_id
AND l.id = end_p.end_id
```

**My Question:** Why I can not achieve the same result using the following query

```sql
SELECT l.*
FROM line AS l, "Layer_2" as p
WHERE ST_within(end_point(l.geometry),p.geometry)
AND ST_within(start_point(l.geometry),p.geometry)
```

However, a query like (see below) will work

```sql
SELECT l.*
FROM line AS l, "Layer_2" as p
WHERE ST_within(start_point(l.geometry),p.geometry)
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refer to `Layer_2` only once, the query would return lines that start and end in the same polygon, as the `p.geometry` used in the two `where` clause conditions must be the same.

You could however change the query to use joins

```sql
SELECT l.*
FROM line AS l
JOIN "Layer_2" p1 ON ST_within(end_point(l.geometry),p1.geometry)
JOIN "Layer_2" p2 ON ST_within(start_point(l.geometry),p2.geometry)
```

Comment: To sum up, this is a direct example of what I have asked before [Difference between JOIN ON and WHERE in Virtual Layers in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324764/difference-between-join-on-and-where-in-virtual-layers-in-qgis), am I right?

Comment: No. Regardless of the joining method, you can access 1 row at a time. If you want to compare 2 rows (2 different polygons), you would need 2 joins

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of theory from [@JGH](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84870/jgh), I ended up with one additional query that will lead to the desired output

```sql
SELECT l.*
FROM line AS l, "Layer_2" as p1, "Layer_2" as p2
WHERE ST_within(end_point(l.geometry),p1.geometry)
AND ST_within(start_point(l.geometry),p2.geometry)
```

Comment: Taras, are you sure that your request works correctly?

Comment: Cyril, it gives me an output, however, I am not that much sure if this query is correct/coherent.