# Find polygons that overlaps in the same layer with SQL

Tags: qgis, sql, overlapping-features

I have one layer with 40k polygons and I would like to create new layer only with the polygons that overlap each other.
I have tried to use the SQL in the db manager in order to create some separation but seems like I cannot run the query on one layer.

this is how I tried to do that:

```
SELECT "45k_less".*,
ST_Overlaps("45k_less"."geometry","45k_less"."geometry") "overlaps" 
FROM "45k_less"
```

I have also tried the same with contains but seems like I miss something here -- maybe because it's the same layer?

I saw there is way to do it with the topology checker but is there any way to do this query inside the db manager?

Comment: For instance there is an overlap between feature 1 and feature 2 in the same polygon layer. Does it have to work both ways i.e. feature 1 intersects feature 2 and at the same time feature 2 intersects feature 1, so the resulting table will include them both like relation 1-to-1 or more like 1-to-many?

Comment: the idea for me would be to have each feature once (lets say if one polygon intersects with 5 others, I would like to have all the six polygons in my table ,each one once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to the way you'd find duplicates in an attribute, you need to join the layer to itself and then exclude self overlaps. So a query like:

```
select a.name, b.name 
from us_counties.states a, us_counties.states b
where a.fid <> b.fid and ST_Touches(a.geom_4269, b.geom_4269)
```

Or

```
select a.name, b.name from us_counties.states a
JOIN us_counties.states b 
ON a.fid <> b.fid and ST_Touches(a.geom_4269, b.geom_4269)
order by a.name, b.name
```

Note I'm using ST_Touches as I have no overlaps in my data, this gives

```
"name","name-2"                                                                                                         
"Kansas","Oklahoma"                                                                                                     
"Kansas","Missouri"                                                                                                     
"Kansas","Nebraska"                                                                                                     
"Kansas","Colorado"                                                                                                     
"Oregon","Idaho"                                                                                                        
"Oregon","Nevada"                                                                                                       
"Oregon","California"                                                                                                   
"Oregon","Washington"                                                                                                   
"Texas","Oklahoma"                                                                                                      
"Texas","Louisiana"                                                                                                     
"Texas","New Mexico"                                                                                                    
"Texas","Arkansas"                                                                                                      
"Idaho","Nevada"
...
```

Comment: Best practice is to use the `JOIN` keyword instead of a list of tables in the `FROM`, and the `a.fid <> b.fid` returns twice as many rows as `b.fid > a.fid`

Comment: If I was looking for simple overlaps I would use `>` but for touches you want `<>` or the result is non-symmetric. I know I should use `JOIN` but I'm old.

Comment: I think what Vince mentioned was my previous question [Difference between JOIN ON and WHERE in Virtual Layers in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324764/difference-between-join-on-and-where-in-virtual-layers-in-qgis). Vince can you be so kind and collaborate your comment/explanation and add it as an answer to my question. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This query will check for self intersection of each feature

```
SELECT *
FROM "45k_less"
WHERE St_IsValid(geometry) = 0
```

Comment: If I understood right the question is not about self-intersections but about finding valid polygons which overlap.

Comment: So, it is when feature 1 intersects feature 2 in the same polygon layer? Am I correct? Does it have to work both ways i.e.  feature 1 intersect feature 2 and  at the same time feature 2 intersect feature 1?